# Cannot compile maven Spring Boot project after jOOQ version upgrade

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-11, jooq

After upgrading to the commercial 3.16.8 version of jOOQ (org.jooq.pro-java-8) my maven compile stage start to fail. Same result is noticeable when upgrading to java-11.

What I found out is that the new version does not work with the following structure.

```
Select sql = ....;
List<CustomTypeClass> result = sql.fetch(this::recordToCustomTypeClass);
```

where recordToCustomTypeClass is a function that takes Record and transform it to a CustomTypeClass.

Does anyone knows why this is no longer applicable?

The error with java 8 is general java error, with java 11 we have more direct message.

JAVA 8:

> java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_251). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
> java: java.lang.AssertionError4

JAVA 11: functional interface not applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using raw types with the jOOQ API (i.e. `Select` rather than `Select<?>`, or some explicit type bound). This is rarely a good idea both with jOOQ or with Java in general. In the case of jOOQ, the API explicitly excludes maintaining raw type backwards compatibility, which would be exceptionally hard to achieve, see e.g.:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/semantic-versioning/ (look for "raw type")
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11879

You should be able to fix this issue by avoiding raw types.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, sir. An additional question is there any performance comparative between ".fetch(this::recordToCustomTypeClass)" and ".fetchInto(CustomType.class)" where CustomType have "@ConstructorProperties". And which would you advice to use

Comment: @G.Min can you please ask a new question? It's not related to the original one, so others wont find my answer here in the comments